# Sending XML data, would T4 templates be a good way?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.0, t4

I would like to send XML data using HTTP POST like the following
(Actually there are more nodes and parameters)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header><Header>
...........cutdown..................
<ID>[set a variable value here]</ID>
<Pass>[set a variable value here]</Pass>
<Footer></Footer>
```

I'm wondering if T4 templates would be one good way to implement it.
Would it? Or should I just make the xml file to read it and set parameters in it?

Comment: How would you implement this with a T4 template?

Comment: seems like generating xml from xml template.. you can use XmlDocument and some XPath to do it all.

Comment: check this for t4 template http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179341/t4-template-transformtext-method-xml-documentation

Comment: hmmm.Sounds better just to use XmlDocument. Thank you.

Comment: And XDocument is a lot easier than XmlDocument. Maybe not for XSLT but for anything else.

Comment: I will use XDocument. Thank you Henk.

Answer (score 0):

T4 runtime tempaltes will work for this, but the Razor template engine is also rehostable and is a worthwhile choice to consider for generating output from a template where that output is pointy bracket based.